# Swift Small to Large Nav Bar Title Jumpy Transition

Tags: swift, tabs, navbar, titlebar

So on my first vc I have set the nav bar to a large title. Then I have a button which goes to a vc with a nav bar with a small title.

When I go back from my second vc to the first, it displays the small title for a bit then jumps down to the large title.

Here is my code in the first vc bc its a tab view controller:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

Here is the code for the second vc in the viewDidLoad():

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 20)!]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

[This is what I mean about the jumpy transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AAuW.gif)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your second ViewController Try changing the NavBarPreference inside viewWillDisappear function.

Example:

```
func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool){ 
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
```

So before going back to the first vc you change the NavBar preference first

Alternative Solution: Using Storyboard

You can click on the desired VC then click on its navBarItem then go to your right to properties and on Large Title Select Never, Always or Automatic from the dropdown list.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5oi5.png)

Comment: it still does the thing where it starts as a small and moves to big. see jumpy transition gif above ^^^^

Comment: that shouldn't happen. Make sure you are not changing the preferences in many different places.

By the way you can also do the desired effect through  the storyboard...wait I will update my answer....

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is to not rely on `largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic` (the default value) and `prefersLargeTitles = true/false` but instead to be explicitly setting `.always` or `.never` with `prefersLargeTitles = true` (yes even when using never).

You need to always have prefersLargeTitles to be true because of this from Apple doc:

> If the prefersLargeTitles property of the navigation bar is false, this property has no effect and the navigation item’s title is always displayed as a small title.

This is an issue you have on iOS11/12 but on iOS13 it will be surfaced a bit differently.